# won't set method work with conditional value parameter

Tags: jsf

won't set method work with conditional value parameter like

```
<h:inputText value="#{empty foo.firstproperty ? foo.secondproperty : foo.firstproperty}" />
```

I got this error:

> Illegal Syntax for Set Operation

is there a way?

**EDIT**

```
public class foo {
    private String firstproperty;
    private String secondproperty;

    public String getFirstproperty() {
        return firstproperty;
    }

    public void setFirstproperty(String firstproperty) {
        this.firstproperty = firstproperty;
    }

    public String getSecondproperty() {
        return secondproperty;
    }

    public void setSecondproperty(String secondproperty) {
        this.secondproperty = secondproperty;
    }
}
```

> /baa.jsp(39,0) '#{empty foo.firstproperty ? foo.secondproperty : foo.firstproperty}' Illegal Syntax for Set Operation

Comment: could u post foo class and full stack trace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set operation **requires** a property with a *plain setter method*, i.e. is in the form of `#{bean.property}` with `public void setProperty(SomeClass property)` in the backing bean. The EL opertaions to set the property won't work as you thought they would (despite the fact that getters will indeed work with your EL expression, for example in `<h:outputText>`).

That said, the solution is quite simple: have two `UIInput` components in your view and conditionally render one of them depending on the value of bean property:

```
<h:inputText value="#{fooBean.firstProperty}" rendered="#{not empty fooBean.firstProperty}"/>
<h:inputText value="#{fooBean.secondProperty}" rendered="#{empty fooBean.firstProperty}"/>
```

In such setting only one of the input components will be rendered and will be bound to a property you want.

---

Also, be sure to adhere to Java naming conventions, which in your case translates to:

- Start a class name with a capitalized letter (not `public class foo` but **`public class Foo`**) and
- Camel case fields and methods within your classes (not `private String firstproperty` but **`private String firstProperty`** and not `public String getFirstproperty()` but **`public String getFirstProperty()`**).